# How to change to null rows containing lowercase letters

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the query code below, for which I want to replace rows when begins with `FOLIC` and replace with `null` the rows that have lowercase (not all are uppercase)

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCvMMcfT19FNwVNBwcg1x1HV2DPIPcfVz1VSK1YlWKsssSczNzFNwBvNQhFzBPF9Hdz/XYM9QXzCvKjMvGaESTAR4+AcDcZB/aDBC0M3fx9NZwdHZ00UpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [FRUITS = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"FRUITS", type text}}),
    Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "WITHOUT LOWERCASE", 
                            each 
                                if Text.Start(Text.From([FRUITS]),5)="FOLIC" then "NOT VITAMIN"
                                else if [FRUITS] = Text.Lower([FRUITS]) then null
                                else [FRUITS]
                            )
in
    Custom1
```

This is how it looks the added column and the expected output I'm looking for. Is almost working but in the rows that have upper and lower case letters (vitamin C, vitamin E) is not converting to null.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it the opposite way.

```
[...]
else if [FRUITS] <> Text.Upper([FRUITS]) then null
[...]
```

Or like this:

```
if Text.Start(Text.From([FRUITS]),5)="FOLIC" then "NOT VITAMIN"
else if [FRUITS] = Text.Upper([FRUITS]) then [FRUITS]
else null
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as you said. Not sure what is the logic error in my original attempt doing it with Text.Lower()

Comment: Yours would work if you only wanted all lowercase strings to become null. The mixed case means that it doesn't match Text.Upper or Text.Lower transformations.